# I want to use multi_select_flutter package, and didn't understand what to pass in MultiSelectItem" arguments

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I want to use multi_select_flutter package, what does "MultiSelectItem" arguments take ?

https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

study properly package example section, you have to map you list,

your list:

```
static List<Animal> _animals = [
    Animal(id: 1, name: "Lion"),
    Animal(id: 2, name: "Flamingo"),
    Animal(id: 3, name: "Hippo"),
    Animal(id: 4, name: "Horse"),
    Animal(id: 5, name: "Tiger"),
    Animal(id: 6, name: "Penguin"),
    Animal(id: 7, name: "Spider"),
    Animal(id: 8, name: "Snake"),
    Animal(id: 9, name: "Bear"),
    Animal(id: 10, name: "Beaver"),
    Animal(id: 11, name: "Cat"),
    Animal(id: 12, name: "Fish"),
    Animal(id: 13, name: "Rabbit"),
  ];
```

mapping with MultiSelectItem:

```
  final _items = _animals
      .map((animal) => MultiSelectItem<Animal>(animal, animal.name))
      .toList();
```

now assign this list in parameter :

```
MultiSelectChipField(
                items: _items,
                initialValue: [_animals[4], _animals[7], _animals[9]],
                title: Text("Animals"),
                headerColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue[700], width: 1.8),
                ),
                selectedChipColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]),
                onTap: (values) {
                  //_selectedAnimals4 = values;
                },
              ),
```